# WordPress customizer: load controls in a custom div

Tags: php, javascript, theme-customizer, options

I have a custom div (holder for extra settings) which I need to load some specific controls from a specific section in there. I can get the controls in JavaScript but I can't generate the necessary HTML as WordPress do in sections.

```
wp.customize.section( 'custom_div_1' ).controls();
```

It gives an array of controls but how to generate the HTML like **Site title** or **Tagline** controls in default WordPress section.

This custom div will toggle by the left button **Open extra settings**.

Screenshot for easier understanding:[image: screenshot]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you add your code please, have you read https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API#Developing_for_the_Customizer

Comment: of course, I read. No need for codes, the concept is clear, we have a section and want to load the controls in a custom div instead of the default customiser section.

Comment: have you try with css only?

Answer (score 1):

Put below codes in your functions.php

```
function sorcey_customize_register($wp_customize){

$wp_customize->add_section('sorcey_footer', array(
  'title'    => __('New Section', 'text_domain'),
  'description' => '',
  'priority' => 120,
));


/*  =============================
      Text input
===============================*/
$wp_customize->add_setting("sr_copyright", array(
        "default"       => "",
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
        "transport" => "postMessage",
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, "sr_copyright_ctrl",
        array(
            "label" => __("Title", "text_domain"),
            "section" => "sorcey_footer",
            "settings" => "sr_copyright",
            "type" => "text",

        )
    ));

}

add_action('customize_register', 'sorcey_customize_register');
```

Then chek there will be a 'New Section'

Answer (score 1):

Use below function for add custom field in customize setion,

```
function custom_register_theme_customizer( $wp_customize ) {

$wp_customize->add_section( 'custom_new_section_featured' , array(
        'title'      => 'Featured & content',
        'description'=> '',
        'priority'   => 94,
    ) );


$wp_customize->add_setting(
            'custom_featured_sliderhd', 'sanitize_callback' == 'esc_url_raw' ,
            array(
                'default'     => false
            )
        );


$wp_customize->add_control(
            new WP_Customize_Control(
                $wp_customize,
                'featured_sliderhd',
                array(
                    'label'      => 'Disable Featured  POSTS',
                    'section'    => 'custom_new_section_featured',
                    'settings'   => 'custom_featured_sliderhd',
                    'type'       => 'checkbox',
                    'priority'   => 1
                )
            )
        );



}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'custom_register_theme_customizer' );
```

For example I used check box, You can update what you want.

Comment: You need add extra div in default section in customize then you need to customise $wp_customize->add_control() function by using "section" and "settings" arguments